# How to use a single Index.php file for many pages

Tags: php

Iam making an app which has one index.php file. I also have these other pages:

```
contact_form_homepage.php 
contact_form_config.php 
contact_form_doc.php 
contact_form_stats.php 
contact_form_premium.php
```

Iam looking for a way I can have all the pages linked to the index.php such that whenever a user clicks Home it takes him to contact_form_homepage.php and whenever he clicks Config it takes him to contact_form_config.php and so on and forth

i.e

```
<a href="http://apps.facebook.com/mtkenya-dev/index.php?p=contact_form_config&amp;tab=contact_form_config&amp;page_id=" title="contact_form_config" class="fbtab">Configuration</a>
```

Which php magic should I use? Kindly help

Comment: include( $_GET['p'] ); is a good place to start. Also consider if p is not in the url.

Comment: Please good god no! Also consider if $_GET['p'] = 'http://domain.com/mylovelyDBScript.php'

Comment: possible duplicate of [how do websites do this index.php?something=somepage](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/548821/how-do-websites-do-this-index-phpsomething-somepage)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do one thing, depending on the query string paramter like "p=contact_form_config",
you can load appropriate page in index.php file.

d.g for when query string parameter is p=contact_form_config then you can use the below code

```
if($_GET['p'] == "contact_form_config ")
{
    // you can load your page now
    include_once('contact_form_config.php');
}
```

Hope this will be helpful :)

Comment: Pushkar, thanks alot, let me try all these options and give my feedback to you all. Thanks all

Comment: your method is the easiest of all

Comment: Could you please vote on this question if everything is working.

Comment: that part I sought now works. I still need your help though, could I get you on social media??

Comment: Please share with me your social media.
I will add you soon :)

Answer (score 0):

My usual technique is to include a php module. I usually put mine in site/`action`.php

You can see this at line 105 of the [standard index.php](http://zxaf.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/zxaf/trunk/index.php?revision=52&view=markup) from my framework.

```
// get the action
$ac=get_from_get('p');
$ua = "";
$is_mvc = 0;

// if no action specified this is the default action.
if ($ac=="")
    $ac="login";

// attempt include the PHP for the action
$file = "site/$ac.php";
if (file_exists($file))
    include($file);
else
{
    header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
    exit;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Richard, thats great!! Let me check it out, I learn so quick with live examples

Answer (score 0):

Simply do a link like you said above...

```
<a href="http://apps.facebook.com/mtkenya-dev/index.php?p=contact_form_config&amp;tab=contact_form_config&amp;page_id=2" title="contact_form_config" class="fbtab">Configuration</a>
```

Then you can read the page_id variable in php code with...

```
if($_GET['page_id'] == 2) {
header("Location: contact_form_config.php");
}
```

Comment: where in the code do I place

if($_GET['page_id'] == 2) {
header("Location: contact_form_config.php");
}

Comment: Probably the near the top (under <?php)... But you need to make sure the create if statements for every page you want to redirect to...

Comment: yours is quite the easier to understand but let me try all options am that liberal

Comment: Please show me an example of using if statement using just this page contact_form_config.php . After that I will do my due dilligence in working out the rest. thanks

Comment: The example is above just notice how in the link above I included `page_id=2`

Comment: Thanks alot, it works like magic, case closed thanks to all of you!!